# Why is my data property being updated by a computed property in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a computed property (***filteredMeasurementsByAttribute***) that is supposed to provide a filtered version of a data property (***measurementsByAttribute***). However, the changes on the computed property are also taking place on the data property.

The filter is using the data from ***selectedAttributes*** (which are the options selected in drop downs on the front end) and then returning the matching data in ***measurementsByAttribute***. This filter is working properly. The issue is that when I run the ***clearAttribute*** method which clears the data from ***selectedAttributes*** (this part works successfully) the ***measurementsByAttribute*** property is the filtered version so I can't get the old data back.

In short, I want to keep an original version of the ***measurementsByAttribute*** property so that I clear the ***selectedAttributes*** property and have all the original data available for ***filteredMeasurementsByAttribute*** to reset the drop down forms.

I've tried saving the data in a regular javascript variable, ***measurementsByAttributeMaster***, and then setting the ***measurementsByAttribute*** to the master. Somehow they all end up just having the filtered values.

I've tried changing the way that I'm looping through the data (e.g. using forEach instead of filter or map) just to see if that was causing it to edit the original data. No luck. I've left the "original" versions using the filter and map in commented out code so you can see both versions.

Any insight or help is very much appreciated.

```js
/**
 * Select Product
 */

function filterMeasurements(attribute, measurementsAvailable) {
    var filteredMeasurements = [];

    attribute.measurements.forEach(function(measurement) {
        if (measurementsAvailable.includes(measurement.id.toString())) {
            filteredMeasurements.push(measurement);
        }
    });
    // return attribute.measurements.filter(function(measurement) {
    //     return measurementsAvailable.includes(measurement.id.toString());
    // });

    return filteredMeasurements;
}

/**
 * Check if the part matches the selected Attributes
 *
 * @param {array} selectedAttributes Array of all the currently selected attributes
 * @param {object} part The part we are checking
 * @retrun {array} the fitlered selectedAttributes
 */
function checkPartAttributes(selectedAttributes, part) {

    var partAttributes = JSON.parse(part.attributes_json);

    // Loop through each selected attribute to ensure there aren't any conflicts
    return selectedAttributes.every(function(measurementID, attributeID) {

        // if no measurement has been selected, it is acceptable
        if (measurementID == "") {
            return true;
        }

        // if the part does have this attribute, it needs to match
        if (attributeID in partAttributes) {
            return partAttributes[attributeID] == measurementID;
        }

        console.log('here');

        // If the part doesn't have this attribute, it is acceptable
        return true;

    });

}

// var SelectSpecifications = require('./components/SelectProduct/SelectSpecifications.vue');

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#select-product',
    components: {
        SelectSpecifications
    },
    data () {
        return {
            allParts: allParts,
            measurementsByAttribute: measurementsByAttribute,
            selectedAttributes: selectedAttributes,      
        }
    },
    computed: {
        /** 
         * combine all the attributes from the matching parts
         *
         * @return {array} The filtered attributes 
         */
        filteredAttributes: function() {
            var filteredAttributes = JSON.parse("{}");
            console.log('filteredAttributes');

            // loop through each matching part and create new array of the matching attributes
            this.matchingParts.forEach(function(part) {

                var partAttributes = JSON.parse(part.attributes_json);

                for (attributeID in partAttributes) {

                    // Add to the index if already exists
                    if (attributeID in filteredAttributes) {

                        filteredAttributes[attributeID].push(partAttributes[attributeID]);
                        filteredAttributes[attributeID] = [...new Set(filteredAttributes[attributeID])];

                    // create the index if it doesn't already exist
                    } else {

                        var tempArr = [partAttributes[attributeID]];
                        filteredAttributes[attributeID] = tempArr;

                    }

                }
            });

            return filteredAttributes;
        },

        /**
         * filter the measurements by selected values
         * @return {object} All the filtered measurements sorted by attribute
         */
        filteredMeasurementsByAttribute: {
            get: function() {

                console.log('filteredMeasurementsByAttribute');

                var selected = this.selectedAttributes;
                var filteredMeasurementsByAttribute = [];
                var filteredAttributesKeys = Object.keys(this.filteredAttributes);
                var filteredAttributes = this.filteredAttributes;

                this.measurementsByAttribute.forEach(function (attribute, index) {

                    console.log(attribute);
                    var tempAttribute = attribute;
                    // filteredMeasurementsByAttribute[index] = tempAttribute;

                    if (filteredAttributesKeys.includes(tempAttribute.id.toString())) {

                        var filteredMeasurements = filterMeasurements(tempAttribute, filteredAttributes[tempAttribute.id]);                    
                        tempAttribute.measurements = filteredMeasurements;
                        filteredMeasurementsByAttribute[index] = tempAttribute;

                    }

                });

                // return measurementsByAttribute.map(function(attribute) {

                //     if (filteredAttributesKeys.includes(attribute.id.toString())) {

                //         attribute.measurements = filterMeasurements(attribute, this.filteredAttributes[attribute.id]);
                //         return attribute;

                //     } 

                // }, this);

                return filteredMeasurementsByAttribute;

            },
            set: function(newMeasurementsByAttribute) {
                console.log('setter working!');
                this.measurementsByAttribute = newMeasurementsByAttribute;
            }
        },

        // returns matching parts depending on what attributes are selected
        matchingParts: function() {
            console.log('matchingParts');
            return this.allParts.filter(checkPartAttributes.bind(this, this.selectedAttributes));
        },
    },
    methods: {
        clearAttribute: function(attributeID) {
            this.$set(this.selectedAttributes, attributeID, "");
            var tempArray = [];
            this.filteredMeasurementsByAttribute = tempArray.concat(measurementsByAttributeMaster);

            // this.selectedAttributes.splice(0);
        },
        kebabTitle: function(title) {

            if (title == null) {
                return '';
            }

            return title.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2")
             .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
             .toLowerCase();
        },        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, setting a variable to an object only copies the *reference* to the object. In `data()`, you've initialized `this.measurementsByAttribute` to a local variable named `measurementsByAttribute`, so any changes to `this.measurementsByAttribute` would affect the original variable.

The problem is observed in the getter for `filteredMeasurementsByAttribute`, which modifies `this.measurementsByAttribute` and thus the original variable:

```js
filteredMeasurementsByAttribute: {
  get: function() {
    this.measurementsByAttribute.forEach(function (attribute, index) {
        // tempAttribute refers to original object in `this.measurementsByAttribute`
        var tempAttribute = attribute;

        if (filteredAttributesKeys.includes(tempAttribute.id.toString())) {
            // ❌ this changes original object's prop
            tempAttribute.measurements = filteredMeasurements;
        }
    });

    //...
  }
}
```

One solution would be to:

1. Apply `Array.prototype.filter()` to `this.measurementsByAttribute` in order to get the measurements that match the filter selection.
2. and use `Array.prototype.map()` and [the spread operator to shallow-clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) the original objects with their `measurements` prop modified.

```js
filteredMeasurementsByAttribute: {
  get: function() {
    const filteredAttributesKeys = Object.keys(this.filteredAttributes)

    return this.measurementsByAttribute
      /* 1 */ .filter(m => filteredAttributesKeys.includes(m.id.toString()))
      /* 2 */ .map(m => ({
                ...m,
                measurements: filterMeasurements(m, this.filteredAttributes[m.id])
              }))
  }
}
```

Comment: You're the hero I needed! This worked just fine and made me finally understand the difference between creating a variable in Javascript and other languages like PHP. I didn't realize that JS just made a reference. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating the change to the original attribute when the computed prop is changed.

```
// ...
filteredMeasurementsByAttribute: {
// ...

 set: function(newMeasurementsByAttribute) {
                console.log('setter working!');
                this.measurementsByAttribute = newMeasurementsByAttribute;
            }
        },
//...
```

I would just have the compute prop apply filter and return the result, but do not have any
`set` on the compute.

If you want the original attribute but have reactive attributes everywhere in the component, it may help to use a different variable.

```
const measurementsByAttributeClone = {...measurementsByAttribute};

// any changes to `measurementsByAttribute` will not impact `measurementsByAttributeClone`
```

Comment: I only have the setter because i was trying to "reset" it back to the original value. It was doing this even when i got rid of the setter. If you look at the clearAttribute method that actually uses the setter then you'll see that i am in fact already trying to use a cloned variable, which in this case is called measurementsByAttributeMaster. I have that set outside of this js file even